# How to fix ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpFilter

Tags: java, maven, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I'm getting an ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpFilter after starting an app.

Filter has to redirect unlogged users to login page

Pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.8</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

AuthenticationFilter.java

```
@WebFilter("/to-do/*")
public class AuthenticationFilter extends HttpFilter {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (AuthenticationService.isAuthenticated(req)){
            super.doFilter(req,res,chain);
        }else{
            res.sendRedirect("/");
        }
    }
}
```

Tomcat Log:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpFilter
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
[...]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpFilter
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1344)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1172)
    ... 59 more
```

When I comment an @WebFilter app works fine. I've tried to add fiter in web.xml and it dosen't work too ;/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use at least Tomcat version **9** — `HttpFilter` was introduced in *Servlet 4.0*.

[Tomcat 8 is providing](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) *Servlet 3.1*, which does not have that class available.

Another approach is to add dependency `javaee-api` when using version 8.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>8.0</version>
</dependency>
```